# Can you change the default look of java swing outside of the application?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jvm, themes

So I noticed (and correct me if I'm wrong) that the default look of java swing appears to be governed by libraries built into the JVM and not packaged with the application. My question is; could you change the look of a java applications that use the default swing style by altering the JVM itself? (note I don't mean the JVM code, I mean the library that comes with the JVM). As in could you distribute a JVM with an operating system that provides a different look for java?

Comment: Short answer is yes, but probably not the way you're thinking. The look and feel API is customisable, and there are a number of 3rd party libraries available

Comment: I was only thinking of changing the colors and graphics, not the location or size of any element. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes. Maybe start with [Modifying the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html)

Comment: Can this be done to the jvm itself? Would you have to modify rt.jar?

Comment: No, and I'd discourage you from trying

Comment: See I'm thinking about creating a basic operating system with a Linux kernal and I wanted to add openJDK and I was curious if a basic theme could be applied to java applications as well

Comment: In theory, if you're willing to make a custom build of the jvm, then it's possible. You want to look at the UIManger

Comment: I recommend using `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`. No fuss, no muss, and the controls will have the 'look and feel' of the OS it is running on. Note that borders and margins will be different across those looks, so it is vital to use layout managers.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) under **Other Screen Shots** for the look in Windows, OS X & Linux (GTK).

Comment: `java -Dswing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel…`?